# Android privacy curtain

Tags: android, react-native, privacy

I am building an app with react native and I have set privacy currtain on iOS when app is in the background, so you wouldn't see screen contents when user double taps home button. I am not sure how I can do the same with android - how can I add overlay that hides screen content when user clicks multitask button.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't speak with regards to React Native, but the standard Android solution is not to "add overlay", but to add `FLAG_SECURE` to the window showing your activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! What about using static image? Is there a flag for that? Can you refer to an example?